# Google Admin Directory SDK Users.list() Returning Old, Not Current, Data

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a project for my company, that well is kind of complicated. I am not sure if I will be able to explain it as well as I need to.

Basically, this is how it works:

1. A user fills out a Google Form that represents a user in our company, either new or existing
2. My Google Apps Script gets the last form response, triggered on form submission
3. That script then relays that last form response data to the custom schema fields I set up on Google Admin
4. Once the user is updated, I grab ALL the users in the domain and paste them into a google sheet

The spreadsheet represents our company roster. We originally just tried to maintain the data solely in a spreadsheet, but it became a mess.

To solve this, we introduced the google form, which can validate all data. Furthermore, our data is backed up to Google Admin (within custom schema). The spreadsheet is solely for display. It is bulletproof. Upon refresh, it pulls the data, and re-writes the sheet.

However...

I am noticing that after the form is submitted and the user is updated in Google Admin, and then all the users are pulled from Google Admin, the user that was updated isn't showing as updated in the spreadsheet. However, if I refresh the page, then the correct data shows up (I have another script that triggers on spreadsheet open, literally the SAME EXACT code that runs after the form submission). Why does that code return the proper data on refresh, but not when run directly after the form submission and consequent user update in Google Admin?

I really am dumbfounded and having an incredibly hard time explaining this because it does not make any sense. My boss and I both spent the entire day scratching our heads on this yesterday.

Do you guys have ANY ideas?

Is there a cached response, possibly accounting for the non-current data from Google Admin?

When I used the Admin Directory SDK API Explorer, the user modified shows as current. I just don't seem to be getting that same response when my script runs.

I am so lost. I spent 2 months developing this system. It worked in development.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Google Admin user changes generally have propagation time, and since you are pulling user information from Admin from the script right after update, the data you are getting may not be updated.

I suggest you delay your user fetching using [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds).

Comment: @CarlosM dude...I think you are right...I did two things...I wrote a while loop to compare the user I updated against what google admin has, and once they match, then I update the sheet. But even that didn't work. BUT...adding an 8 second delay after a match and THEN updating the sheet, THAT WORKED. I need more time to verify, I'll let you know.